# How to integrate a count variable in a Java stream expression

Tags: java, java-stream

The following approach does not compile (variable `i` should be final):

```
  void appendLines(StringBuilder sb, String str) {
    str.lines().forEach(s -> {
      int i = 0; 
      sb.append("\n  [").append(i++).append("] ").append(s).append("\n");
    });
  }
```

An ugly workaround:

```
  void appendLines(StringBuilder sb, String str) {
    class Counter {
      int i = 0;
      int inc() {
        return i++; 
      } 
    };
    Counter i = new Counter();
    str.lines().forEach(s -> sb.append("\n  [").append(i.inc()).append("] ").append(s));
  }
```

I think, there should be a more elegant solution, maybe with

```
static <T> Stream<T> iterate(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> f)
```

, but unfortunately I don't know how to use it.

Comment: A workaround would be to use an Atomic or and int-array with a length of one. But definitely better would be to think of implementing your solution in some other way.

Comment: Something like: `static void appendLines(StringBuilder sb, String str) {AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();str.lines().forEach(s -> {sb.append("%n  [%d] %s%n".formatted(i.getAndIncrement(), s));});}` You might want to look at the width of that digit formatter

Comment: @g00se This is a great solution. much thanks. But the parentheses around `sb.append(...)` are not necessary.

Comment: Or `static String formatLineNumbers(String str) {AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();return str.lines().map(s -> "%n  [%d] %s%n".formatted(i.getAndIncrement(), s)).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));}` Yes, true about the curly braces

Comment: @g00se The first one is better, because I need to append to an existing StringBuilder.
A little culprit is, that with `String.formatted()` an additional String should be created, to be thrown away again.

Comment: Not only `formatted` creates an intermediate string; `lines()` does it too. Maybe you’re better off with a loop, e.g. `void appendLines(StringBuilder sb, String str) {
    for(int p = 0, e, i = 0; p < str. length(); i++, p = e + 1) {
        e = str.indexOf('\n', p);
        if(e < 0) e = str.length();
        sb.append("\n  [").append(i).append("] ").append(str, p, e).append("\n");
    }
}` This creates no temporary strings.

Comment: Yes but not *sb.append("\n *. `System.lineSeparator()` or you could get mixed line feeds

Comment: @Holger You are right, your example would be the least resource consuming solution.
Well, I came from a solution with `string.split()`, and then I found that the Stream-Solution is stated faster and less consuming. So I got curious, to code my first Stream usage. :-)

Comment: It's got to be said that if these resource consumption distinctions are in any way significant, you *really* don't want to be using Java in the first place ;)

Comment: You can use the Stream API like `int[] i = { 0 }; Pattern.compile("^.*$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(str).results() .forEach(mr -> sb.append("\n  [") .append(i[0]++).append("] ").append(str, mr.start(), mr.end()).append("\n"));` to avoid temporary strings. However, the kludge for the counter still makes this task not suitable for streams…